# how to get the value selected in this jquery slider

Tags: jquery, slider, jquery-slider

here is the code

```
<script> 
  $( ".slider" ).slider({
    animate: true,
    range: "min",
    value: 0,
    min: 0,
    max: 4,
    step: 1,

  //this gets a live reading of the value and prints it on the page
  slide: function( event, ui ) {
    if(ui.value ==0)
      $( "#slider-result" ).html( "Poor");
    else if(ui.value == 1)
      $( "#slider-result" ).html( "Average");
    else if(ui.value == 2)
      $( "#slider-result" ).html( "Good");
    else if(ui.value == 3)
      $( "#slider-result" ).html( " Very Good");
    else if(ui.value == 4)
      $( "#slider-result" ).html( "Excellent");                     
    },

  //this updates the hidden form field so we can submit the data using a form
  change: function(event, ui) { 
    $('#hidden').attr('value', ui.value);
    }
  });
</script>
```

this slider create a jquery slider and display "excellent  verygood good poor" and so on. on selecting . now i need to get the value of slider selected how to do that????

Answer (score 1):

Your code is setting the `value` of an element with `id` "hidden" when the slider changes. See the line:

`$('#hidden').attr('value', ui.value);`

You should therefore be able to get the current value of the slider by getting the value of that element:

`var currentValue = $('#hidden').val();`

However, the hidden input with `id` "hidden" does not have an initial value, so this won't work if the slider has not yet changed. You can fix that by giving a value to that hidden input element.

I am assuming the entire reason you have it updating a hidden input element on change is so you can access that value at some point...

Answer (score 0):

slider value is stored in the... value: `$(".slider").slider.value`